# How to create coupon code to be used only by people who have subscribed to the newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, coupon, coupon-codes

I need a help to create a **15% OFF** coupon code for products.

This coupon is only for people who have subscribed to our newsletter.

As far as I know, there is no option in Magento to do so, but is there anyone who can help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

First Create a Shopping Cart Price Rule for 15 % Off, now use that rule in your custom module.

```
class Namespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
{
public function getCouponCodecustom(){

    try {

        $data = array(
            'rule_id' => 123,
            'qty' => 1,
            'length' => 8,
            'format' => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
            'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
            'uses_per_customer' => 1
        );
        $generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
        $generator->setData($data);
        $generator->generatePool();

    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with coupon: %s', $e->getMessage()));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with coupon.'));
    }
 }
}
```

You can get the coupon code in Newsletter by short code {{var subscriber.couponCodecustom}}

```
Newsletter Subscription Success
Thank you for subscription, your coupon code <b>" {{var subscriber.couponCodecustom}} "</b>
```

Thats it!